# Output list of even Fibonacci numbers in Euler prob 2 with Python 2.75

Tags: python, list, python-2.x, fibonacci

How to output results in list form (with code not manually) on Python 2.75.
Instead of solving just for the sum I inserted `print i` then sum and got the numbers visible (11 of them). Please help with this very basic question. Thank you.

```
##Even Fibonacci numbers Problem 2
##Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms.
##By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be: 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55...
##By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed
##four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.
import fibo
sum = 0
a = fibo.fib2(4000000)
for i in a:
    if i%2==0:
        print i
        sum += i
print "the sum of these even Fibonacci numbers = "
print sum
###how to create list or tuple of the
##even_fib=[2, 8, 34, 144, 610, 2584, 10946, 46368, 196418, 832040, 3524578]
```

Comment: Where does `fibo` come from?

Comment: What do you mean by 'list form'? In the form of a python list?

Comment: FIBO "module" http://code.google.com/p/trypython/source/browse/trunk/trypython/app/fibo.py?r=145

Answer (score 1):

Start with an empty list and as you find them append them on:

```
even_fib = []

for i in a:
    if i %2 == 0:
        even_fib.append(i)
```

The result will be a list of all the even elements

Comment: Thanks! in one of many variations I defined the empty list and used "list" where it was correct to use "append." [so close! and I already learned 'append', but not for empty lists]. Also I tried to fix the error message for list(): list' object has no attribute 'list' and along the way errors , such as "non iterable" and so on.... but couldn't "fix" it. Finally, I tried using generator/itertools and so on -- are any of these fixit attempts a viable alternative? thanks again!